# Is a visa necessary for a 1-month unpaid internship in the Netherlands?

Tags: student-visa, internship

I am currently in France on a long-stay student visa. I got an internship offer in Holland for a month. Can I move there without applying for another visa? Also the internship is unpaid.

Comment: What is your nationality?